# List Items in Unordered List Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've read the w3c standard guides, and they state that for basic form creation, using a ul is superior to using a table.  In Firefox, etc, the very simple code shown below creates simple text/input box pairs, in a list.

In internet explorer (Ie8, 9), the text boxes appear ~15px beneath and to the right of the spans.

[image]

Could someone explain to me why?  What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        ul li input
        {
            width:70%;
            float:right;
        }
        ul
        {
            list-style: none;
            width:300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <span>Username:</span><input type="text" id="UserNameBox" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <span>Password:</span><input type="password" id="PasswordBox" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the inputs to float right, then the following HTML should work:

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="text" id="UserNameBox" /><span>Username:</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" id="PasswordBox" /><span>Password:</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: This link should help you understand what float means: http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_float.html

Answer (score 0):

the `<input>` tag is self closing, your html syntax is wrong on the inputs.  Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span>Username:</span><input type="text" id="UserNameBox" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <span>Password:</span><input type="password" id="PasswordBox" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My mistake, I typed this out a bit too quickly.  I tried this, and it did not fix the issue though.